# Executing seed command dynamically through controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to build a small application on `Laravel` with modular approach, I am having a controller method which seeds the database as per the module/plugin name:

I have something like this:

```
Artisan::call('db:seed --class=Nitseditor\\Plugins\\'.$pluginName.'\\Databases\\seeds\\InstallSeeder');
```

Whenever I am calling this I am getting this error in my console.

> Class NitseditorPluginsConfidenceDatabasesseedsInstallSeeder does not exist

I don't know why it remove `\` and concatenate the strings.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: HOw did you create the seeder? have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @ggdx I already did `composer dump-autoload`. I created the seeder manually as it belongs to one of the modules in my application.

Comment: Try `"db:seed --class=Nitseditor\Plugins\$pluginName\Databases\seeds\InstallSeeder"` (quotes, not apostrophies)

Comment: Try `--class="Nitseditor\Plugins\XXX\Databases..."` instead.

Comment: @KFoobar It will give `Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".`

Comment: @ggdx Same error. No change!

Comment: @RolandStarke How can I call my plugin/module name. I mean how can I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$fullClassName = "Nitseditor\\Plugins\\${pluginName}\\Databases\\seeds\\InstallSeeder";

Artisan::call("db:seed", ['--class' => $class]);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case when i have some module in subfolders

then want to run one of the Seeders directly without running other seeders

```
php artisan db:seed --class=WM\Common\Seeder\SmsStatusSeeder
```